# the css file stops working after a while

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

My style.css file was working great (I checked my html file on web browsers and it appeared just the way I wanted) However, after a while, all web browsers stopped following some codes in the style.css file that had worked well just a couple minutes ago, even though I made no changes to those parts (particularly, those codes were the a hover, a visited). 
I am using Audobe Dreamweaver CC and I am new to HTML and CSS.
Thank you!
_______________________________________style.css____________________________________

```
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: Arizonia;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: calibri;   
    font-size: 36px;
    color: red;
}
ul#nav1 {
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul#nav1 li a: link {
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;  
}
ul#nav1 li a: hover{
    color: orange;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family:jokerman;
}
ul#nav1 li a: active{
    color: red;
}
ul#nav1 li: visited{
    color: white;
}
ul#nav li{
    display: inline;
}
ul#nav {
    padding: 20px;
    list-style-type: ||;
}
ul#nav li a: link {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: green;
    list-style-type: upper-roman;   
}
p.ul#nav li a: hover{
    color: orange;
}
ul#nav li a: active{
    color: red;
}
ul#nav li: visited{
    color: purple;
}
table, th, td {
    align-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    boder-spacing:5px;
    padding:10px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size:20px;
}
.right {
    position:absolute;
    right:80px;
    width:auto;
}
```

_______________________________________index.html____________________________________

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tự bạch của Trần Minh Triết</title>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="header">
<marquee> Chào mừng đến với trang tự bạch của Trần Minh Triết </marquee>
</div>
<hr/>
<h1>SITEMAP</h1>
<ul id="nav1">
<li><a href="background.html">Trần Minh Triết là ai?</a></li>
<li><a href="milestone.html">Chặng đường tôi đã đi qua</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery yêu thích của tôi</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Hãy liên lạc với tôi</a></li>
<li><a href="makefriend.html">Tôi rất muốn biết về bạn, bạn nghĩ sao?</a></li>
</ul>
<img src="index/footer.jpg" style="width:1366px;height:auto">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a concise reproducible example - in its current form no-one will be able to accurately answer your query. I would take a guess that you have some syntax errors in your CSS which is stopping the styles from being applied.

Comment: I am sorry. I am kind of at a loss of how to post the whole css file up here. However, I think I figured it out!

Comment: Actually I don't understand ur question properly. `ul#nav1 li a: link`in this code u have put a space between **:** and **link** This will result in no operation. Avoid space, use like `ul#nav1 li a:link`

Comment: Thank you Hidden Hobbes for correcting my way-of-asking!

Comment: Thank Rekesh Rajan: It works beautifully now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your CSS which need to be fixed. The specific issue with your links is that you have spaces between the element and pseudo class. To fix change:

- `ul#nav1 li a: link` to `ul#nav1 li a:link`
- `ul#nav1 li a: hover` to `ul#nav1 li:hover`
- `ul#nav1 li a: active` to `ul#nav1 li:active`
- `ul#nav1 li a: visited` to `ul#nav1 li:visited`

I would suggest running your CSS through a [validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). `list-style-type: ||;`, for example, is not valid.